# Ubuntu on the Dell XPS 8920

Tags: dell

I am considering to buy one of the Dell XPS 8920 machines, and would like to check beforehand if I can expect them to run smoothly under Ubuntu. Has anybody such a system working in dual-boot Linux/Win10? I read on some articles that this is/was slightly problematic, hence the question.

Comment: Isn't there a "hardware compatibility guide" or similar for Ubuntu? At least there used to be. Anyway, bring a live USB (or DVD if the machine has a drive) to a store & give it a try on a demo, if a store's got one set up. Or if the return policy's good just buy it & try it right away, if it's no good (& can't find fixes online) then return it. PS. Here's a fairly comprehensive looking UEFI install guide https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: there is a list of "ubuntu certified computers", this one is not included. nor is my previous one which also worked fine ...

I am planning to order online, so I can't test it in a store. But thanks for the link to the UEFI guide, I'll have a look

Comment: Yeah, most desktops work good with Ubuntu/Debian, disabling UEFI used to be a good answer but win might complain, should be ok now enabled. Only sometimes the hardware sensors or fan control might look a little off (low/high readings, but look like they work), or need a boot code to run (old acpi conflict warning). cpufreq often just works. Video drivers may have some hoops to jump through but should eventually work... Pretty much "just try it & google for fixes"... Or try asking the seller if it's compatible with Ubuntu XX.YY?

Comment: I decided to order the computer, and it arrived today. One problem that I currently have is about dual booting with the pre-installed windows 10: If I boot in UEFI mode (from a live system on a USB drive), the  M.2 PCIe SSD is not visible to the partition manager. It is visible if I boot in legacy mode, but then windows fails to start. Any ideas how to get out of this?
 256GB M.2 PCIe x4 SSD + Tray load DVD Drive (Read